# How Can I Get Remote FileName on Host When download it via ASIHttpRequest

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

How Can I Get Remote FileName on Host When download it via ASIHttpRequest??

for example, some url like this:

> http://www.filedropper.com/processing/filedownload.php?id=test_22

test_22 is my filename, but original string is @"test_22.gif" , i can not analysis the filename extension from url.

i am trying to get responseString for the real filename when ASIHttpRequest call it delegate method :

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
    didReceiveResponseHeaders:(NSDictionary *)responseHeaders
```

but i got nothing useful.

any idea?

Comment: See if the response headers include `Content-Disposition` or `Content-Location`.

Answer (score 0):

i hope, you can get file name through the following code..see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147311/finding-image-type-from-nsdata-or-uiimage) to find file type.after finding append it..

```
 NSString *url = @"http://www.filedropper.com/processing/filedownload.php?id=test_22";
 NSArray *parts = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
 NSString *filename = [parts objectAtIndex:[parts count]-1]; // or NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];
```

Comment: but original string is @"test_22.gif"

Comment: did u try NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];

Comment: it returns @"test_22", but i need is @"test_22.gif"

Comment: dont give down vote if answer is not satisfied to you...you should find out the text after "." which comes after "=",and then you should append it ...this is a help..