# How to get image metadata from NATIVE_URI in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I am developing a phoneGap application in IOS where I use  `getPhoto('Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY');` 
to access the photo library and select an image. following is the onPhotoURISuccess method where I need to get the url of the image and pass it to my native plugin to validate it's filesize, resolution and file extension, later i need to convert it to Hex.

this is my getPhoto() method

```
        // A button will call this function
    function getPhoto(source)
    {            
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,
                                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI, sourceType: source });

    }
```

and this is the onPhotoURISuccess method

```
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI)
{
    img_uri = imageURI;
    console.log('NATIVE_URI==>'+img_uri);

    // Get image handle
    var imgPrev = document.getElementById('imgPreview');

    // Unhide image elements
    imgPrev.style.display = 'block';

    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    imgPrev.src = imageURI;

    validateImage(imageURI);
}
```

I have three options for this according to the phoneGap documentation. using DATA_URL, FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI.
FILE_URI seems to be hiding underlying data of the image where it always returns me a peg image and even I couldn't get the filesize of the image as well. but NATIVE_URI seems to have the metadata within it for an instance, i got a path like this

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=5CF16D20-9A80-483A-AC1C-9692123610B1&ext=JPG
```

I want to know how to get the metadata of the image like the filesize and file extension from this.