# Get the text after the last char-type in string

Tags: ios, swift3, nsstring

I have the following string type:

`file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1C02189F-2426-4420-A178-1CC420CBBD3A/tmp/com.test.Test-Inbox/2015-04-23_00002.jpg`

And I need to access the file extension which in this case is `.jpg`

I want to access the string after the last `.` since it will always be the file extension I want, but I cannot substring it to the last 3 chars because the extension might have 4 chars like `.docx` or `.mpeg`

What would be the best way to do this?

I thought in reverse the string and loop char by char to get the latest (in this case first) `.` and then as I find the length I could substring it.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828044/is-it-possible-to-find-the-file-extension-of-a-uiimage

Comment: that case is specific for images, and in my case the file could be of any type, and I get a pointer URL instead of a raw NSData type. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.components(separatedBy:)` to break the `String` into substrings separated by a certain character (*"."* in your case). Since you know the file extension will be after the last separator, you can just call `.last` on the array of substrings to access it.

```
let fileNameWithExtension = "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1C02189F-2426-4420-A178-1CC420CBBD3A/tmp/com.test.Test-Inbox/2015-04-23_00002.jpg"
let fileExtension = fileNameWithExtension.components(separatedBy: ".").last
```

Comment: whoa.. that's great, didn't new that `String` functionality

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift3**, You can easily get from path only. No need of doing any extra stuff.

```
let filePath:NSString = "the_file_name.png"
let fileExtension = filePath.pathExtension
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this.

```
let string = "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1C02189F-2426-4420-A178-1CC420CBBD3A/tmp/com.test.Test-Inbox/2015-04-23_00002.jpg"
let all = string.components(separatedBy: ".")
let ext = all.last
print(ext)
```

Comment: this is great!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by

```
NSURL *stringFilePath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1C02189F-2426-4420-A178-1CC420CBBD3A/tmp/com.test.Test-Inbox/2015-04-23_00002.jpg"];

NSString *fileName = [stringFilePath lastPathComponent];
```

And get extension

```
NSLog(@"%@", fileName.pathExtension)
```

**For Swift :**

```
let stringFilePath:NSString = "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1C02189F-2426-4420-A178-1CC420CBBD3A/tmp/com.test.Test-Inbox/2015-04-23_00002.jpg"
let strFileExtenson = stringFilePath.pathExtension
print(strFileExtenson)
```

Comment: The question clearly asked for `Swift`, so why an Objective-C answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let fileNameWithExtension = "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1C02189F-2426-4420-A178-1CC420CBBD3A/tmp/com.test.Test-Inbox/2015-04-23_00002.jpg"
let url = URL(string:fileNameWithExtension)
print(url?.pathExtension ?? "")
```