# How to get the URL of a selected image using phonegap application

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I’m using camera.getPicture() method to open up the photo library and let the user select an image. this is my reference

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

We can get the image as a base64 string or can get its URI and use in our application in from the function `onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI)`. 
I select the URI because It is easy for me to process. I got stuck because the image is returned always as jpeg and even the image’s fileSize cannot be measured. I traced the URI by debugging and it’s always similar to the below

```
file://localhost/Users/user/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/B50E3AD6-74F8-43F6-9F91-F28D2B06DF62/tmp/cdv_photo_116.jpg
```

It’s trying to save the image locally and takes any image with the extension of jpg.
I’m wondering how to solve this issue.Does anyone have any idea on how we can get the URL of the image from this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I didn't get an answer I went on digging the phoneGap documentation and finally got the answer. following is my code samples. note that the file extension identifying method is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147311/finding-image-type-from-nsdata-or-uiimage)

I have a button control in my html (in the phoneGap application) page as below
anyone can refer the phoneGap documentation from [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions). It's so helpful.I have used version 2.9.0

```
<button onclick="getPhoto(Camera.pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button>
```

and in my javascript, I have the function getPhoto() as below

```
function getPhoto(source)
    {        
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,
                                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI, sourceType: source });
    }
```

once, a photo is selected, this delegate will be called

```
   function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Get image handle
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      largeImage.src = imageURI;

      checkFileExtention(imageURI);
    }
```

checkFileExtention() function asynchronously calls the method of file extension checking at the native side. For the simplicity, I post only the application logic part

```
//functions checks the type of the image passed
- (NSString *)contentTypeForImageData:(NSString *)imageUrl
{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    
    uint8_t c;
    [imageData getBytes:&c length:1];
    
    switch (c)
    {
        case 0xFF:
            return @"image/jpeg";
        case 0x89:
            return @"image/png";
        case 0x47:
            return @"image/gif";
        case 0x49:
        case 0x4D:
            return @"image/tiff";
        case 0x42:
            return @"@image/bmp";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

When getting the FILE_URI it saves the image locally and sends a URI which looks like below
file://localhost/Users/user/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/B50E3AD6-74F8-43F6-9F91-F28D2B06DF62/tmp/cdv_photo_116.jpg

apparently, the file type is hidden because it's always indicating as jpg

when NATIVE_URI is used, it looks like this
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=5CF16D20-9A80-483A-AC1C-9692123610B1&ext=JPG
note that above uri shows JPG becasue the image is JPG, else the real file extension of the selected image is shown.

ultimately, if when the native uri is sent to the contentTypeForImageData funtion, it gives me the correct output

Comment: you are a life savior!