# Phonegap iOS: Share saved image /Retrieve last saved image file URI

Tags: ios, canvas, cordova, share

I'm building a Phonegap app which saves the content of a canvas to camera roll (I do that with the Canvas2ImagePlugin), now I'd like to share this saved image using the SocialSharing PhoneGap Plugin but I need to fill the image URI field to use the plugin. How can I do that?

I've got a saveImage() function that pretty much does what it says: runs the plugin saving my canvas to image and alerts when the image is saved in the camera roll.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
    function(msg){console.log(msg);},
    function(err){console.log(err);},
    document.getElementById('canvas')
);

alert("Saved!");
```

I'm open to other solutions to share (fb & twitter mostly) the content of my canvas.
Thanks

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far, and then someone may be able to help you.

Comment: I added the code I use to save my image, but I can't integrate the SocialSharing plugin with that. Any advice is appreciated, I don't necessary have to use that plugin, I'm open to other solutions

Comment: what does this "function(msg){console.log(msg);}," log?

Comment: This is the plugin function to log the correct saving of the canvas to png in the camera roll, it basically says something like "SAVED". The saveImageDataToLibrary plugin part works very well, I'd like to know how to share my saved image from the app whithout opening the camera roll and selecting it.

Comment: One option would be the base64 encoded image, but I'm not sure social sites accept that. Have you tried looking here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859731/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-selected-image-using-phonegap-application

Instead of letting the user pick the image to share you could automatically pick the last one save in the library, which will be your image if it has just been saved.

Comment: The page you gave me works when the image is selected from the photo library, as seen in the phone gap camera documentation http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html
Anyway, what you say is exactly my idea: once the image is saved in the camera roll, the path to that image is saved in a variable (no clue how to retrieve the right path) and then, if the user wants to share the image, I can use that variable to fill the image part of the SocialSharing Plugin.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I'm having the exact same problem.  It's very annoying the way android defines the path to the recently saved canvas in the callback but ios does not due to its underlying image handling.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help now, but I forked the canvas2image plugin and modified it to return the file path in iOS instead of "Saved".  It's been approved by Adobe Build and can be found here:
https://github.com/wbt11a/Canvas2ImagePlugin

The pull request has been acknowledged but is still pending.  Hope it helps.