# How to detect if an image (a GIF) is animated or still

Tags: ios, swift, image

I need to check if an image is animated or ordinary image. Is there any method in iOS to check this?

I think a file with gif extension can be still image or animated image.

How can I check if it's animated or still image?

Comment: Do you have Data object or UIImage?

Comment: check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5042365/2677551)

Comment: a file with gif may be animated or not animated. right. am not looking for file extention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone that still comes here looking for an answer in Swift. Just to get if the image is an animated gif, this is the simplest I could come up to.
This is working fine on **Swift 4**. For Swift 4.2 a couple changes were made to the delegate methods, but nothing major.

**THIS ONLY WORKS ON IOS 11+, if you need support for 9/10 see below.**

```
func isAnimatedImage(_ imageUrl: URL) -> Bool {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl),
          let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil) {

        let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
        return count > 1
    }
    return false
}
```

and in my case I'm getting the image from a UIImagePickerController

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {

    if let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL {
        let isImageAnimated = isAnimatedImage(imageURL)
        print("isAnimated: \(isImageAnimated)")
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

**IOS 9 and 10**

For iOS 9 and 10 theres no way to get the `UIImagePickerControllerImageURL` since it's a new iOS 11 thing, so we need to use the Photo library to fetch the data from.

Import Photos Library at the top

```
import Photos
```

Add the correct code to fetch data

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {

    if let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {

        let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageUrl], options: nil)
        if let image = asset.firstObject {
            PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: image, options: nil) { (imageData, _, _, _) in
                let isImageAnimated = isAnimatedImage(imageData)
                print("isAnimated: \(isImageAnimated)")
            }
        }


    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func isAnimatedImage(_ imageData: Data) -> Bool {
    if let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData as CFData, nil) {
        let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
        return count > 1
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with PDFs, Weirdly enough CGImageSourceGetCount returns page count for PDFs. And PDF is not an animated image. CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(dataRef, 0, nil); fails to load a pdf into an image. Be careful what you pass in the URL. NOT A VALID METHOD to check if it's animated image or not.

Answer (score 1):

the following code snippets maybe help you.

Basically, it uses CGImageSourceGetCount to get the count of images for gif files. Then, it depends on the count to do a image action or the animation action.

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data, NULL);

size_t count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source);

UIImage *animatedImage;

if (count <= 1) {
    animatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
}
else {
    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSTimeInterval duration = 0.0f;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        CGImageRef image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
   ....
    }
}
```

Those codes from [[轉]用UIImage承載GIF圖片](http://likeabossapp.com/2016/05/02/%E8%BD%89%E7%94%A8uiimage%E6%89%BF%E8%BC%89gif%E5%9C%96%E7%89%87/)

Answer (score -1):

It is really possible but you may create your own method to do that by extending the NSData class.

here is the detail of getting an image extension: [Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104538/6501597)

Comment: a file with gif may be animated or not animated. right. am not looking for file extention.

Comment: Well I answered based on your question. This was your question:

"How to detect gif is Animate GIF in IOS

As part of a project need to check the selected image is Animated gif or ordinary image. Is there any method in ios to check this.

Thanks in advance"

Comment: You updated your question 47 minutes after I answered your initial question.