# How to show if image is on pasteboard in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uipasteboard

I want to show pasteboard content in an `UIImageview` if pasteboard contains image.

How can I do it? I tried with `UIPasteboard`, but how can I check which type of image it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the type of data to show the image, just do:

```
UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CopyPaste" create:YES];
NSData *data = [appPasteBoard dataForPasteboardType:@"com.yourCompany.yourApp.yourType"];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

However, you could guess the type by looking at the first byte ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5042365/386738)):

```
+ (NSString *)contentTypeForImageData:(NSData *)data {
    uint8_t c;
    [data getBytes:&c length:1];

    switch (c) {
    case 0xFF:
        return @"image/jpeg";
    case 0x89:
        return @"image/png";
    case 0x47:
        return @"image/gif";
    case 0x49:
    case 0x4D:
        return @"image/tiff";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use only like this? `let image = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image!
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`

Comment: `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().items` is what you should be looking for. This contains information about the image and image itself.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622067-items?language=objc