# Check if fetched object is Image or Video in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I want to check what type the latestObject is. Here's some code:

```
allMedia = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(fetchOptions)
let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: fetchOptions)
let allVideo = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: fetchOptions)
print("Found \(allMedia.count) media")
print("Found \(allPhotos.count) images")
print("Found \(allVideo.count) videos")

let latestObject: AnyObject! = allMedia.lastObject

// How to check what type latestObject is?
// I think something with mediaType but how is it exactly going?
```

Comment: check : 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582717/how-to-check-a-file-is-video-or-image   2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145844/iphone-how-to-check-if-the-file-is-a-directory-audio-video-or-image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
if let asset = allMedia.lastObject as? PHAsset {
    switch asset.mediaType {
    case .Image:
        print("Image")
    case .Video:
        print("Video")
    case .Audio:
        print("Audio")
    default:
        print("Unknown")
    }
}
```

Each element contained in the `PHFetchResult` is a `PHAsset` (in this case).
So, with casting to `PHAsset`, you can access the property `mediaType`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can check it in UIImagePickerController delegate method 

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

  if((info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] as! String) == "public.movie" ){
    // Video file
  }
  else{
    // Image
  } 
}
```

Comment: I don't use UIImagePickerController