# How to get the file extension from an AVAsset or AVAssetTrack

Tags: swift, avfoundation, file-type, avasset

I've a audio file (mp3, wav, aiff, ...) in an `AVAsset` then get the `AVAssetTrack`.

I'm looking for a way of finding the audio file type (mp3, wav, aiff, ...) from this asset in a Apple format like `AVFileType` or `AudioFileTypeID`?

For the moment the only way I find to get the audio file type is to use `formatDescriptions` property of `AVAssetTrack` and get the subType as showed in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassettrack/1386694-formatdescriptions) but it doesn't work very well since I cannot determine which uncompressed format I have (wav or aiff) because I just get "lpcm" format...

Isn't possible to get the `AVFileType` from an `AVAsset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you acquiring the asset? You can try casting to AVURLAsset, get the URL, and finally the pathExtension.

Comment: Thanks indeed it's a solution. Btw could we get the audio file format in Apple format like `AVFileType` or `AudioFileTypeID`?

Comment: You can compare the UTI to the extension, https://medium.com/@francishart/swift-how-to-determine-file-type-4c46fc2afce8 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243371/path-extension-and-mime-type-of-file-in-swift (last answer I think is more correct)

Comment: Thanks George, it was what I was looking for! When I get the uti string I can create an AVFiletype with init(rawValue:)