# WKWebView open PDF in external browser

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an IOS app that navigates to a web page using a WKWebView. The page itself contains back buttons in the menu. When we click on a link to a PDF, the pdf itself displays in the view, but the other html content (including back buttons) disappears.

Is there any way for me to detect when a link returns a PDF and open that content externally in safari or a similar browser?

If that's not possible is there a way for me to detect when a link returns a PDF and show the web kit back buttons (just for that page).

Edit: Clarification

The link clicked to go to the pdf doesn't actually contain the pdf text. The link  looks something like /Documents/GetDocument?docid=1234.

The content returned is of type application/pdf. In an ideal world we would be able to see the content returned from the link, and then handle appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
  extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        print(navigationAction.request.url ?? "")
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString{

        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

And don't forget to assign

```
 webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

The above method will get called when ever webview tries to load a new url and as per your comment and updated question you want to check the mime type of url. For that you can refer to

1. [This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40003309/2299040)
2. [Library](https://github.com/sendyhalim/Swime)

Comment: So the url itself doesn't actually contain the text pdf, the pdf itself is returned from a url with posted parameters, I will update the question with that info

Comment: just compare the url.relativePath to "/Documents/GetDocument", if it matches, "decisionHandler(.cancle)" and do "UIApplication.shared.openURL(request.url") to have it open in Safari