# How to download files in wkwebview

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Anybody  please tell me how to download files in iOS wkwebview. I have created an iOS webview app. In the page I have loaded It has several download options but when I click download nothing  happened.

Note: I dont want to create extra buttons to download

Comment: check this out [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108394)

Answer (score 29):

Since `macOS 11.3` and `iOS 14.5` we have finally an API to deal with downloads.
But at the time of writing this (June, 2021), documentation is still quite limited: [WKDownloadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkdownloaddelegate)

## 1. WKNavigationDelegate

### 1.1

Add a `WKNavigationDelegate` to your `WKWebView.navigationDelegate`

### 1.2

On your `WKNavigationDelegate` implement:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, preferences: WKWebpagePreferences, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.shouldPerformDownload {
        decisionHandler(.download, preferences)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.allow, preferences)
    }
}
```

This will get called when clicking any link.

`navigationAction.shouldPerformDownload` will be true when the WKWebView detects the link is meant to download a file.

### 1.3

Also on your `WKNavigationDelegate` implement:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationResponse.canShowMIMEType {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    } else {
        decisionHandler(.download)
    }
}
```

This will get called if you answered `decisionHandler(.allow, preferences)` on the first method, meaning the WKWebView didn't recognise the link as a download, and will try to display it.

`navigationResponse.canShowMIMEType` will be false if the WKWebView realises it can't display the content.

## 2. WKDownloadDelegate

### 2.1

Create a `WKDownloadDelegate`

### 2.2

In your `WKWebView` implement:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, didBecome download: WKDownload) {
    download.delegate = // your `WKDownloadDelegate`
}
    
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, didBecome download: WKDownload) {
    download.delegate = // your `WKDownloadDelegate`
}
```

One of these methods will be called when you answer `.download` to any of the methods described on section `1.`. The first will be called if it was the first method and second if it was the second method.

You need to assign a delegate to each download, but it can be the same delegate for all of them.

### 2.3

In your `WKDownloadDelegate` implement:

```swift
func download(_ download: WKDownload, decideDestinationUsing response: URLResponse, suggestedFilename: String, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
    let url = // the URL where you want to save the file, optionally appending `suggestedFileName`
    completionHandler(url)
}
```

This will get called when WKWebView is ready to start a download, but needs a destination URL.

### 2.4

Optionally, also in your `WKDownloadDelegate` implement:

```swift
func downloadDidFinish(_ download: WKDownload) {
        
}
```

This will get called when the download finishes.

---

#### Final notes

- Remember both delegates are not retained by the WKWebView, so you need to retain them yourself.
- There are a few more methods on `WKDownloadDelegate` useful for dealing with errors, check the documentation for more details (link provided above).
- Important to remember this is only supported on `macOS 11.3` and `iOS 14.5`.
- As mentioned before, documentation is still scarce, I just finded how to make this work by trial an error, any feedback appreciated.

Comment: WKDownload Delegate methods not called? any suggestion

Comment: @YogeshPatel are any of the methods mentioned on 2.2 called?

Comment: Yes I found that it will always going on .allow not in .download. I remove .allow and add .download then it called WKDownloadDelegate Methods.

Comment: With using then can I able to download audio file?

Comment: @YogeshPatel Maybe the WKWebView is trying to play the audio file instead of downloading it. By replacing .allow by .download then you should be able to download files.

Comment: Yes I did this thing and it will save in document directory but not playing size showing only 5KB. can you help on this?

Comment: one more thing wkwebview will automatically detect that this url is for allow and for download like. any condition or any thing? thanks!

Comment: @YogeshPatel Not sure why the file doesn't get downloaded completely, maybe you could ask a new question askin that.

Comment: @YogeshPatel WKWebView detects if the url is supposed to be downloaded or open/played, you can help this detection by using the `download` parameter on the `a` HTML tag, example: `<a href="file.pdf" download>Download File</a>`

Comment: okay thank you for your suggestion. I will try. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can also use JavaScript to download your file, as [Sayooj's link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108394) implys.

Of course, you will handle the file downloaded code yourself.

With `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,  decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {` , you get the file url to download.

Then download it with JS.

the JS call a downloaded method if success, you will be notified with `public func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {`  ,

Then you can handle your downloaded file

**It is a little complicated. Use JavaScript to download file, use WKScriptMessageHandler to communicate between native Swift and JavaScript.**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {  
  
    var webView: WKWebView!  
    let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()  
    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        
        // init this view controller to receive JavaScript callbacks  
        webViewConfiguration.userContentController.add(self, name: "openDocument")  
        webViewConfiguration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsError")  
        webView = WKWebView(frame: yourFrame, configuration: webViewConfiguration)  
    }  
      
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,  
                 decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,  
                 decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {  
        let url = navigationAction.request.url  
        decisionHandler(.cancel)  
        executeDocumentDownloadScript(forAbsoluteUrl: url!.absoluteString)  

    }  
      
    /* 
     Handler method for JavaScript calls. 
     Receive JavaScript message with downloaded document 
     */  
    public func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {  
        debugPrint("did receive message \(message.name)")  
  
  
        if (message.name == "openDocument") {  
            handleDocument(messageBody: message.body as! String)  
        } else if (message.name == "jsError") {  
            debugPrint(message.body as! String)  
        }  
    }  
      
    /* 
     Open downloaded document in QuickLook preview 
     */  
    private func handleDocument(messageBody: String) {  
        // messageBody is in the format ;data:;base64,  
          
        // split on the first ";", to reveal the filename  
        let filenameSplits = messageBody.split(separator: ";", maxSplits: 1, omittingEmptySubsequences: false)  
          
        let filename = String(filenameSplits[0])  
          
        // split the remaining part on the first ",", to reveal the base64 data  
        let dataSplits = filenameSplits[1].split(separator: ",", maxSplits: 1, omittingEmptySubsequences: false)  
          
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: String(dataSplits[1]))  
          
        if (data == nil) {  
            debugPrint("Could not construct data from base64")  
            return  
        }  
          
        // store the file on disk (.removingPercentEncoding removes possible URL encoded characters like "%20" for blank)  
        let localFileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename.removingPercentEncoding ?? filename)  
          
        do {  
            try data!.write(to: localFileURL);  
        } catch {  
            debugPrint(error)  
            return  
        }  
          
        // and display it in QL  
        DispatchQueue.main.async {  
            // localFileURL  
            // now you have your file
        }  
    }  
      
  
  
    /* 
     Intercept the download of documents in webView, trigger the download in JavaScript and pass the binary file to JavaScript handler in Swift code 
     */  
    private func executeDocumentDownloadScript(forAbsoluteUrl absoluteUrl : String) {  
        // TODO: Add more supported mime-types for missing content-disposition headers  
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("""  
            (async function download() {  
                const url = '\(absoluteUrl)';  
                try {  
                    // we use a second try block here to have more detailed error information  
                    // because of the nature of JS the outer try-catch doesn't know anything where the error happended  
                    let res;  
                    try {  
                        res = await fetch(url, {  
                            credentials: 'include'  
                        });  
                    } catch (err) {  
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsError.postMessage(`fetch threw, error: ${err}, url: ${url}`);  
                        return;  
                    }  
                    if (!res.ok) {  
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsError.postMessage(`Response status was not ok, status: ${res.status}, url: ${url}`);  
                        return;  
                    }  
                    const contentDisp = res.headers.get('content-disposition');  
                    if (contentDisp) {  
                        const match = contentDisp.match(/(^;|)\\s*filename=\\s*(\"([^\"]*)\"|([^;\\s]*))\\s*(;|$)/i);  
                        if (match) {  
                            filename = match[3] || match[4];  
                        } else {  
                            // TODO: we could here guess the filename from the mime-type (e.g. unnamed.pdf for pdfs, or unnamed.tiff for tiffs)  
                            window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsError.postMessage(`content-disposition header could not be matched against regex, content-disposition: ${contentDisp} url: ${url}`);  
                        }  
                    } else {  
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsError.postMessage(`content-disposition header missing, url: ${url}`);  
                        return;  
                    }  
                    if (!filename) {  
                        const contentType = res.headers.get('content-type');  
                        if (contentType) {  
                            if (contentType.indexOf('application/json') === 0) {  
                                filename = 'unnamed.pdf';  
                            } else if (contentType.indexOf('image/tiff') === 0) {  
                                filename = 'unnamed.tiff';  
                            }  
                        }  
                    }  
                    if (!filename) {  
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsError.postMessage(`Could not determine filename from content-disposition nor content-type, content-dispositon: ${contentDispositon}, content-type: ${contentType}, url: ${url}`);  
                    }  
                    let data;  
                    try {  
                        data = await res.blob();  
                    } catch (err) {  
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsError.postMessage(`res.blob() threw, error: ${err}, url: ${url}`);  
                        return;  
                    }  
                    const fr = new FileReader();  
                    fr.onload = () => {  
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.openDocument.postMessage(`${filename};${fr.result}`)  
                    };  
                    fr.addEventListener('error', (err) => {  
                        window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsError.postMessage(`FileReader threw, error: ${err}`)  
                    })  
                    fr.readAsDataURL(data);  
                } catch (err) {  
                    // TODO: better log the error, currently only TypeError: Type error  
                    window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsError.postMessage(`JSError while downloading document, url: ${url}, err: ${err}`)  
                }  
            })();  
            // null is needed here as this eval returns the last statement and we can't return a promise  
            null;  
        """) { (result, err) in  
            if (err != nil) {  
                debugPrint("JS ERR: \(String(describing: err))")  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Tell me one more thing what should I have to add in yourframe  mentioned in this line(webview=wkwebview(frame:yourframe,configuration: webviewconfiguration)

Comment: `view.frame`, or `view.bounds`

Answer (score 5):

As  [Sayooj's link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108394) implys:

You have to deal with the download business yourself

After you have download task in WKWebView, you can get the file url to download from method `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,     decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,  decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {`

Then you initiate a download task to download the file, `URLSession` is an option

you can handle the file after downloaded. And the link above shows how to preview your downloaded file with `QLPreviewController`

```
import UIKit    
import WebKit      

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {    

    var webView: WKWebView!   

    var webViewCookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore!  
    let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()  

    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  

        webView = WKWebView(frame: yourFrame, configuration: webViewConfiguration)   
        webView.uiDelegate = self  
        webView.navigationDelegate = self  

        view.addSubview(webView)  
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: yourUrlString))    
    }    


    /*  
     Needs to be intercepted here, because I need the suggestedFilename for download  
     */    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,    
                 decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,    
                 decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {    
        let url = navigationResponse.response.url    

        let documentUrl = url?.appendingPathComponent(navigationResponse.response.suggestedFilename!)    
        loadAndDisplayDocumentFrom(url: documentUrl!)    
        decisionHandler(.cancel)    

    }    

    /*  
     Download the file from the given url and store it locally in the app's temp folder.   
     */    
    private func loadAndDisplayDocumentFrom(url downloadUrl : URL) {  
        let localFileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(downloadUrl.lastPathComponent)  

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadUrl) { data, response, err in  
                guard let data = data, err == nil else {  
                    debugPrint("Error while downloading document from url=\(downloadUrl.absoluteString): \(err.debugDescription)")  
                    return  
                }  

                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {  
                    debugPrint("Download http status=\(httpResponse.statusCode)")  
                }  

                // write the downloaded data to a temporary folder  
                do {  
                    try data.write(to: localFileURL, options: .atomic)   // atomic option overwrites it if needed  
                    debugPrint("Stored document from url=\(downloadUrl.absoluteString) in folder=\(localFileURL.absoluteString)")  

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {  
                        // localFileURL  
                        // here is where your file 

                    }  
                } catch {  
                    debugPrint(error)  
                    return  
                }  
            }.resume()  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: after implemented this one webview showing only white screen @black_pearl

Comment: The code are all Downloading related. No UI Logic. Your Question? Please show some Code

Comment: @StephenBalaji it cause you give decisionHandler(.cancel)... use nomally decisionHandler(.allow) and download condition use decisionHandler(.cancel)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation and the answers here helped me on the way but it was not straight forward to just get up and running in SwiftUI. so here is the code snippet to handle all the download for you.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import OSLog


@available(iOS 14.5, *)
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    lazy var logger = Logger()
    @Binding var editorDownloadUrl: URL?
    var downloadUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> WebViewCoordinator{
        return WebViewCoordinator(self)
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator // very important to add this line.
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-pdf-download/") else { return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}

// MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
@available(iOS 14.5, *)
class WebViewCoordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var parent: WebView
    
    init(_ parent: WebView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, preferences: WKWebpagePreferences, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences) -> Void) {
        return navigationAction.shouldPerformDownload ? decisionHandler(.download, preferences) : decisionHandler(.allow, preferences)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
        navigationResponse.canShowMIMEType ? decisionHandler(.allow) : decisionHandler(.download)
    }
    
}

// MARK: - WKDownloadDelegate
@available(iOS 14.5, *)
extension WebViewCoordinator: WKDownloadDelegate {
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, didBecome download: WKDownload) {
        download.delegate = self
    }
    
    func download(_ download: WKDownload, decideDestinationUsing response: URLResponse, suggestedFilename: String, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileUrl =  documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(suggestedFilename)", isDirectory: false)
        
        parent.downloadUrl = fileUrl
        completionHandler(fileUrl)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Optional
    func downloadDidFinish(_ download: WKDownload) {
        parent.editorDownloadUrl = parent.downloadUrl
    }
    
    func download(_ download: WKDownload, didFailWithError error: Error, resumeData: Data?) {
        parent.logger.error("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        // you can add code here to continue the download in case there was a failure.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## iOS 14.5 +

Just use the SwiftPackage [WKDownloadManager](https://github.com/kuttz/WKDownloadManager)

### OR

Use this class to handle downloads. Only need to specify the mime types that are supported for download.

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

public protocol WKDownloadManagerDelegate: AnyObject {
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor url: URL) -> Bool
   
    func destinationUrlForFile(withName name: String) -> URL?
    
    func downloadDidFinish(location url: URL)
    
    func downloadDidFailed(withError error: Error)
    
}

extension WKDownloadManagerDelegate {
    
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor url: URL) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    public func destinationUrlForFile(withName name: String) -> URL? {
        let temporaryDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: temporaryDir)
            .appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
        
        if ((try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: false)) == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        
        return url.appendingPathComponent(name)
    }
    
    public func downloadDidFailed(withError error: Error) {
        
    }
    
}

public class WKDownloadManager: NSObject {
    
    weak var delegate: WKDownloadManagerDelegate?
    
    fileprivate var downloadDestinationURL: URL?
    
    /// An array of supported Mime types.
    fileprivate var supportedMimeTypes: [String] = []
    
    
    /// Create the WKDownloadManager with a delegate and supported mime types
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - delegate: delegate object
    ///   - supportedMimeTypes: Array of supported Mime types.
    public init(delegate: WKDownloadManagerDelegate,
                supportedMimeTypes: [String]) {
        super.init()
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.supportedMimeTypes = supportedMimeTypes
    }
    
    fileprivate func isSupported(mimeType: String) -> Bool {
        return supportedMimeTypes.contains(mimeType)
    }
    
}

// MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate
extension WKDownloadManager: WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction) async -> WKNavigationActionPolicy {
        
        guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
            return .cancel
        }
        let isSafe: Bool = delegate?.webView(webView, decidePolicyFor: url) ?? true
        return isSafe ? .allow : .cancel
    }
    
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse) async -> WKNavigationResponsePolicy {
        guard let url = navigationResponse.response.url else {
            return .cancel
        }
        
        let isSafe: Bool = delegate?.webView(webView, decidePolicyFor: url) ?? true
        if !isSafe {
            return .cancel
        } else if let mimeType = navigationResponse.response.mimeType,
                  isSupported(mimeType: mimeType) {
            return .download
        } else {
            return .allow
        }
    }
    
    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, didBecome download: WKDownload) {
        download.delegate = self
    }
    
}

// MARK: - WKDownloadDelegate
extension WKDownloadManager: WKDownloadDelegate {
    
    public func download(_ download: WKDownload, decideDestinationUsing response: URLResponse, suggestedFilename: String) async -> URL? {
        downloadDestinationURL = delegate?.destinationUrlForFile(withName: suggestedFilename)
        return downloadDestinationURL
    }
    
    public func download(_ download: WKDownload, didFailWithError error: Error, resumeData: Data?) {
        delegate?.downloadDidFailed(withError: error)
    }
    
    public func downloadDidFinish(_ download: WKDownload) {
        
        if let url = downloadDestinationURL {
            delegate?.downloadDidFinish(location: url)
        }
    }
    
}
```

### Example:

```
fileprivate var downloadManager: WKDownloadManager!

// Supported mime types for download
// Insert mime types according to your need
let mimeTypes = ["image/svg+xml",
                 "image/png",
                 "image/jpeg",
                 "application/pdf"]
downloadManager = WKDownloadManager(delegate: self,
                                    supportedMimeTypes: mimeTypes)
webView.navigationDelegate = downloadManager
```

### Reference :

[WKWebViewDownloadExample](https://github.com/kuttz/WKDownloadManager/tree/main/Example/WebViewDownloaderExample)

[WKDownloadManager](https://github.com/kuttz/WKDownloadManager)

[Common MIME types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66254547/11662833)