# Swift downloading files from PHP headers

Tags: php, ios, swift, macos, wkwebview

I have a wrapper iOS app that uses WKWebView to display a web application.

For file downloads on the web app (written in PHP) we have a download link looking like this:
download.php?id=xyz

The download.php file then processes this and outputs the actual file in the headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($local_location));
header("Content-Type: " . $file_mime_type);
header("Last-Modified: $gmt_mtime");
        
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".$name."\";");
header("Expires: 0");
set_time_limit(0);
        
readfile($local_location);
```

However, nothing happens in the WebView when the download link is clicked.

The session is authenticated, so we can't open the link in the default browser as there would be no authentication headers.

Ideally I'd like the file to save in a specified location (perhaps a popup where a user can select the location) - this is because the app will be compiled for iOS and MacOS.

Could anyone provide some guidance on this please?

Comment: I have no knowledge of Swift but just to correct something: you are not outputting the file in the headers, think of a HTTP message as an HTML document with its invisible head and displayed body.

Comment: Check for [how to download file in wkwebvieW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083340/how-to-download-files-in-wkwebview)