# How to download files from inside WKWebview on macOS

Tags: javascript, macos, swiftui, webview, wkwebview

so I'll keep it short. AS the title says I have an a web view embedded in my SwiftUI application for macOS and there's a link on the website which downloads a .doc file. However WKWebView doesn't really let you know download stuff from the internet like that. I looked around SO and there are a few ways to solve it but none of them pertain to SwiftUI. Does anyone know how can I simply download a normal text file from a website onto the Mac using WKWebView in SwiftUI?

Here's my WebView code:

```
  import SwiftUI
  import WebKit
  import Combine

  class WebViewData: ObservableObject {
  @Published var loading: Bool = false
  @Published var url: URL?;
var popupWebView: WKWebView?
  init (url: URL) {
  self.url = url
 }
 }

 @available(OSX 11.0, *)
 struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {
 @ObservedObject var data: WebViewData

  func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
   return context.coordinator.webView
    }

 func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {

guard context.coordinator.loadedUrl != data.url else { return }
context.coordinator.loadedUrl = data.url

if let url = data.url {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    nsView.load(request)
  }
}

context.coordinator.data.url = data.url
  }

      func makeCoordinator() -> WebViewCoordinator {
    return WebViewCoordinator(data: data)
   }
  }

 @available(OSX 11.0, *)
class WebViewCoordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
  @ObservedObject var data: WebViewData

  var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
  var loadedUrl: URL? = nil

  init(data: WebViewData) {
     self.data = data

  super.init()

webView.navigationDelegate = self
 }

  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.data.loading = false
   }
   }

   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation:     WKNavigation!) {
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.data.loading = true }
   }

  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError.   error: Error) {
   showError(title: "Navigation Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.data.loading = false }
  }

  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    showError(title: "Loading Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.data.loading = false }
  }


  func showError(title: String, message: String) {
#if os(macOS)
let alert: NSAlert = NSAlert()

alert.messageText = title
alert.informativeText = message
alert.alertStyle = .warning

alert.runModal()
#else
print("\(title): \(message)")
#endif
  }
 }
```

Here's my Content View

```
  import SwiftUI

 @available(OSX 11.0, *)

 struct ContentView: View {


 private var url: URL? = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com")

   init() {
print("Hello World")
   }

   var body: some View {
  
  
WebView(data: WebViewData(url: self.url!))
      .frame(minWidth: 1400, idealWidth: 1500, minHeight: 850, idealHeight: 850)
  
  }



 }
```

Also here's how my website downloads the files using JS in case anyone's interested:

```
    function exportworddocument(){
 
   var sourceHTML = document.getElementById("notes").innerHTML;
     
   var source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' +    encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML);
   var fileDownload = document.createElement("a");
   document.body.appendChild(fileDownload);
   fileDownload.href = source;
 
   var lines = $('#notes').val().split('.');//gives all lines
    const firstLine=lines[0];
  console.log(firstLine)
   fileDownload.download = firstLine + ".doc";
   fileDownload.click();
   document.body.removeChild(fileDownload);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your `WebViewCoordinator` implement [`WKDownloadDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkdownloaddelegate/) so it can handle a [`WKDownload`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkdownload). Implement [`webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview/) to call `decisionHandler(.download)` for the files you want to download, and then implement [`download(_:decideDestinationUsing:suggestedFilename:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkdownloaddelegate/3727344-download) to choose the download destination for a given request.

A more expansive answer to a similar question is available at [How to download files in wkwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083340/how-to-download-files-in-wkwebview), and there's a good blog post on the topic at: http://www.gfrigerio.com/download-files-in-a-wkwebview/

Comment: @marchprux I've been messing with those two answers since yesterday and I have't been able to achieve that. This is where I'm stuck right now : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264117/frame-download-error-when-downloading-from-wkwebview-onto-local-drive

Comment: @alex did you manage to figure this out? i'm also on macos

Comment: @swiftnoob hey yeah none of these approaches worked. What worked was using the evaluate Javascript function in swift and then basically grabbing the document to download with its id and just making a blob lol.