# Gif loading and storing

Tags: ios, image, animated-gif, sdwebimage

```
    UIImage *image                = [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromDiskCacheForKey:_actualImageURL.absoluteString];
    if(!image) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderImage"];
        [self makeImageAvailableAtURL:_actualImageURL];
    }

    self.messageImage.image       = [image isImageGif] ? image.images.lastObject : image;
```

We are loading image from server. If it is some **gif** image, we get image with `.images` ( i got no another way how to understand is it gif or not).

```
- (BOOL)isImageGif {
    return self.images;
}
```

But if we store gif image with

```
 [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:image forKey:wImageURL.absoluteString];
```

,it lose `.images` .

Any idea how handle this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147311/finding-image-type-from-nsdata-or-uiimage

Please check  this link

Comment: Well, i checked it. U want me store NSData instead UIImage or so? Understanding where gif or not, i already have ( but dirty).

Comment: NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage.image);
you have to convert it to nsdata .
P.S
You can also create nsdat from a file provide it a url.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/data

Comment: Okay, lets create NSData from image. It will save gif? It will convert to png/jpeg obliviously. And anyway need cache NSData somehow.

Comment: Yes you are right . If you directly query on NSData from provide by the web service it will be good. I guess you have to save nsdata and when you required the image convert it to image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solution is using:

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:image recalculateFromImage:NO imageData:data forKey:key toDisk:YES];
```

instead just:

```
 [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:image forKey:key];
```

I have found it there:
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/916